# How to reduce the Path.Data precision in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am saving a Canvas as Xaml using xaml writer

```
string strXaml = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(rootElement);
```

The xaml that is generated has very large Path.Data

```
<Path Data="M178.061103421175,129.580733852605L193.622508536283,129.579677215608 193.622534058222,129.955546337824 178.383889830182,129.956581058991z M193.434586735851,129.767619032979L193.434579752171,129.586744283962 193.810448874973,129.586729771435 193.810455858653,129.767604520452z M193.622513391756,129.39880246616L200.57609615027,129.398768358939 200.576072204466,124.516836247382 203.668339188234,124.516821079852 203.668339188234,129.66079407036 212.06212740336,129.660752898928 212.06212740336,130.829834481415 224.593555084937,130.829773014925 224.593574452587,134.778336158564 241.618815286431,134.778336158564 241.621014560214,129.643614552785 248.726256699727,129.643588552304
```

Note the extremely large precision after the decimal point. 
I need a way to reduce the precision on these number.

The Canvas is generated by loading a .dwg file using Cadlib, then the cadlib model is drawn on the canvas.

Comment: WAG: have you tried creating your own subclass of `XamlXmlWriter` and overriding `WriteNode()` and/or `WriteValue()`? I would also reconsider whether you really do need to reduce precision. I understand the output may be large, but in what way _specifically_ is this a problem for you? Could you address it through use of compressing the output instead of stripping information from it? Note that compressing text is likely to gain you much more improvement in size (4x-10x is typical) than would trimming precision (which might get you a 2x improvement?).

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for the reply. 
The problem I am facing is with the rendering time. I have the same xaml with smaller path data and that renders very quickly.
I am still not sure where/why those large numbers are coming from ? Any idea ?

Comment: Rendering time is correlated with the _complexity_, i.e. the count of individual shape instructions in the path, and not the _precision_ of each individual number in the path. The only information you've shared with respect to the origination of the values in the path description is that they come from a CAD data file. It seems reasonable to assume that the values come from that. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to provide specific advice. But you might try consider "freezing" the path's geometry before rendering.